# How to send new posts push notifications from Wordpress to PhoneGap (iOS and Android)

Tags: wordpress, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I need to send push notifications to all users of my app (built with PhoneGap).
These push notifications should notify the user that a new post has been posted on a wordpress site.

I used the phonegap's PushNotifications plugin.

Now I need to set up the server side scripts that would actually send the notification payload. I am asking this question because I can't figure out how to do this. Can you suggest some solutions? I did look around stackoverflow, but couldn't find a solution that would work for both iOS and Android, and would work with Wordpress.

Looking forward to any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a particularly broad question with a lot of required pieces but I will attempt to give you a high level implementation.

There are several steps to take to get your **WordPress** site relaying messages to your app's install base.

I would recommend using a provider like [**urban airship**](http://www.UrbanAirship.com) to handle the push notifications workflow.  Urban Airship (and other alike) allows you to support **Android**, **iOS**, **Amazon**, **Blackberry**, etc.  They do all of the maintenance required and also lets you register devices using alias (like email address or other identifiers decides the device tokens/ids)

If you decide to use **Urban Airship** as your **VAN** there is a server side plugin for WordPress called [Blimply](http://wordpress.org/plugins/blimply/).  You can use this plugin to communicate to Urban Airship's API to relay your push notifications to your devices within your Wordpress site.

Comment: Thanks! Urban Airship is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: However, after setting everything up, I can only get it to work with Android. Even though I have set up a certificate and a provisioning profile for iOS, it still does not register with the service and I don't see its Device Token in the Urban Airship's Device Tokens tab. Do you know why this would happen and how I can fix this?

Comment: iOS is a little different.  If your device is not getting a Device Token from apple it is most likely because your apps bundleId/provisioning, apns environment and cert is not matching.  Are you getting any errors like "no valid aps-environment entitlement string found for application" when you attempt to register for notifications on the device?

Comment: where would I look for errors like "no valid aps-environment entitlement string found for application"?

Comment: I saw an error: 
CDVPlugin class PushNotificationPlugin (pluginName: pushnotificationplugin) does not exist.

This is strange as I definitely installed the plugin and it works just fine on Android.

Comment: never mind. I just realised what was causing this error.
 Basically I had another plugin installed called PushNotifications. Its not the same plugin as the Urban Airship's Push Notifications plugin. I tried to remove that other plugin but I got a message that plugin could not be found in the project. So I couldn't manage to get rid of it using the cli. So what I did was just create a new phonegap project and then just added the device and urban airship plugins. Copied the www folder contents into the new project, built it, and now everything works perfectly. Thanks again for great help.

Answer (score 2):

There is a WordPress plugin that does exactly what you ask (disclaimer first: I'm one of the developers). It is called [Push Notifications for WordPress](http://www.delitestudio.com/wordpress/push-notifications-for-wordpress/).

The nice thing is that it integrates perfectly into WordPress and it does not use any third-party’s server (so there is no charge for delivery). It even supports custom post types, analytics, user groups, and so on. You can buy it [here](http://www.delitestudio.com/wordpress/push-notifications-for-wordpress/) (one-time purchase).

Answer (score 0):

There are many for WordPress now since ithaas a large plugin base and eco system like https://wordpress.org/plugins/push-notification-for-wp-by-pushassist/

I tried it and using it for many of my sites. Frankly, for smaller web blogs 3000 subscribers are more than enough. Serious sites should opt for paid plans of any push notification providers.

Answer (score 0):

There are many push notifications WordPress plugins in the WP repository which you can use on your website to send push notifications.

Onesignal is the most popular free push notifications plugin for WordPress. With the easy integration of this plugin, you can set opt-in for your visitors to when and how they want send push notification from WordPress to Phone. Onesignal has a feature of schedule and automatic notifications to online and offline users it means your visitors can receive notifications even after they have left your website.
Source [5+ Best WordPress Push Notification Plugins](http://smallenvelop.com/wordpress-push-notification-plugins/) By SmallEnvelop